# How to handle XML file in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop, archive

How to handle this XML file in hive, I want only USERNAME and PASSWORD in output

```xml
<?XML version=’1.0′ ?>
<DATA>
    <USER USERNAME="ABC" FIRSTNAME="RAJ" LASTNAME="KUMAR" PASSWORD="123" />
    <USER USERNAME="DEF" FIRSTNAME="VENKAT" LASTNAME="BALAJI" PASSWORD="123" />
</DATA>
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_xml(USERNAME string,PASSWORD string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
        "column.xpath.USERNAME"="/DATA/USER/USERNAME/text()",
        "column.xpath.PASSWORD"="/DATA/USER/PASSWORD/text()"
    ) STORED AS
        INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start"="<DATA","xmlinput.end"="</DATA>");
```

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried so far. If you have not tried anything, please refer to this question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852166/how-to-load-xml-file-into-hive

Comment: `xmlinput.start"="<DATA`... Are you missing a close tag there?

Comment: i tried that also but still issue persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got output please refer https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/972/hive-and-xml-pasring.html